# Updating Chromedriver in inteliiJ for MAC m2 chip

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I am trying to run my selenium program getting below error message .

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 115
Current browser version is 118.0.5993.117 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

So I want to change the ChromeDriver from intelliJ so please help me how can I do it.
I have tried to delete the previous ChromeDriver from intelliJ but don't think it will be a right procedure.